# Hiding a column in XSLT by comparing column header

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT.  I have a table in which the number of columns are to be determined by the user dynamically as per need.  The last column in my table allows the user to add a new row and other row transformations.  While I display, I want all my columns of the table except this row transformation column at the end of the table.  Is there any way that I could always hide the last column from display on page?

Since the number of columns is dynamic, I set up a variable called count and got the number of columns. Then, I fetched entire data using

My XML Code:

```
<table id="table_name" class="tf-data-tables_var_cols" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width: 20%;">Link(<span style="color: red;">Required</span>)</th>
<th style="width: 20%;">Categorty(<span style="color: red;">Required</span>)</th>
<th style="width: 20%;">Department</th>
<th style="width: 20%;">Class timings</th>
<th style="width: 20%;">Row Options</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Graduate Studies</td>
<td>Student Info</td>
<td>Graduates</td>
<td>Afternoon</td>
<td><form class="add_row" onsubmit="return addRow(this);"><input type="submit" value="Add Row Below" /></form><br /><form class="delete_row" onsubmit="return deleteRow(this);"><input type="submit" value="Delete Row" /></form><br /><form class="move_row" onsubmit="return moveRow(this, 'up');"><input type="submit" value="Move Up" /></form><br /><form class="move_row" onsubmit="return moveRow(this, 'down');"><input type="submit" value="Move Down" /></form></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

XSLT Code:

```
<xsl:template match="table[contains(@class, 'tf-data-tables_var_cols')]">
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(./thead/tr/th)"/>
        <table id='table_name'>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

I get the full table along with the last column as output.  How do I hide/delete the last column?

[Output I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmJuA.png)
I want to remove the row options

Comment: Please add the expected output of transforming the given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the last column and its header and keep everything else *as is*, you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="th[last()] | td[last()]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. It worked.But since I'm new, I'm not sure if I understand what is going on.  I could see, you have copied everything inside and then when you match th[last()]|td[last()], what does it do?  Remove the last header and last column.  I mean there is no instruction telling XSLT to remove the column.  How does that work?

Comment: The [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) template copies everything as a rule. The 2nd template makes an exception for the `th` and `td` elements that are last children of their `tr` parent. Since the template is empty, no output is produced for them.